# Thinking in python

Tags: python, c

**Magnus Lie Hetland** in his **Beginning python** wrote a code to replicate the range()   built-in.

```
def interval(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None: 
        start, stop = 0, start 
    result = []
    i = start 
    while i < stop: 
        result.append(i)
        i += step 
    return result
```

I re-wrote it like this.

```
def interval(*args):    
    if  len(args)<1:
        raise TypeError('range expected at least 1 arguments, got 0')
    elif len(args)>3 :
         raise TypeError('range expected at most 3 arguments, got %d' % len(args))
    else:
        if len(args)==1:
            start = 0
            stop = args[0]
            step = 1
        elif len(args)==2:
            start=args[0]
            stop=args[1]
            step=1
        elif len(args)==3:
            start=args[0]
            stop=args[1]
            step=args[2]

        result = []
        while start < stop:
            result.append(start)
            start+=step

        return result
```

I know my code is lengthier but don't you people think its easier to grasp/understand than Hetland's code? Different peoples' minds work differently. In my mind the code felt easier to understand cos I come from a **C** background. My emphasis is on code comprehension.

Comment: You got **Magnus Lie Hetland**'s version slightly wrong. The line that reads `i = start` is indented one level too far.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is more straightforward, but its size is a bit daunting. I actually like the original better. The only real 'trick' it uses is multiple assignment. And while it requires you to think through the different cases of `range` a bit to realize it works, this isn't something I mind. In fact, with yours, if I were to verify its correctness I'd have to spend just as much time because it has so much more code.

I tend to prefer code that's a bit terse, but elegantly handles all the cases to code that laboriously checks each case and handles that case with case-specific code. And this is in any programming language.

Comment: Thanks I get the point.less code if not complicated even if complex.

Answer (score 3):

This is bad

```
    while start < stop:
        result.append(start)
        start+=step
```

Don't reuse `start` to be the index of the loop.  It's confusing.  It violates the *meaning* of start.

The lengthy parameter parsing is good, but can be made more clear.  Don't waste time on checking for `<1` or `>3`.  Just use the `if` statement.

```
if len(args)==1:...
elif len(args)==2:...
elif len(args)==3:...
else:
    raise TypeError( "Wrong number of arguments" )
```

Comment: Well,the range() built-in shows the argument No in exception message like **range expected at least 1 arguments, got 0**.I wanted to emulate it.

Comment: @Jibin: "built-in shows the argument number".  That doesn't mean it's **good** design.  It should also be part of the `else` clause if it's so important to provide that kind of message.

Comment: :got that.I think there is a psychological reason to 'why error/exception should be in else case'.Suppose a programmer is reading the code, for first few moments his mind is fresh so main logic should come first,error/exceptions can come last.What do you think?

Comment: "logic should come first,error/exceptions can come last." I'm unclear on how it can be otherwise.  What's the alternative?

Comment: As in my code - the exception comes first in the `if` clause and actual the  calculation of `range` comes last in the `else` clause.

Comment: @Jibin: I'm confused.  First you say "logic should come first,error/exceptions can come last".  I agree with you.  Then you say "the exception comes first in the if clause".  I thought you agreed that the exception should come first.

Comment: Never mind.Thank you for putting up with me this far

Answer (score 2):

You've replaced three named arguments with a variable-length list of anonymous arguments and three seperate ways of mapping list positions onto named variables ... I'd question why that seems clearer to you.

You're then manually enforcing constraints on the variable-length argument list which the interpreter handled for you in the original code.

And, finally, where you `raise` an exception, you don't need to put the following code in an `else` block: if you're coming from **C**, think of the `raise` more like an early return.

eg.

```
def interval(*args):    
    if  len(args)<1:
        raise TypeError('range expected at least 1 arguments, got 0')
    if len(args)>3 :
        raise TypeError('range expected at most 3 arguments, got %d' % len(args))
    if len(args)==1:
        ...
```

(although S.Lott's formulation is better still).

Comment: The problem with the version that has three named arguments is that those names aren't necessarily indicative of what the argument does, i.e. if you call `interval(3)` the name of the first argument is `start` even though its semantics are `stop`. So for that reason alone I think the `*args` version is actually clearer - at least the user won't make any assumptions about what the arguments to without consulting the documentation first.

Comment: OK, good point: the code itself still looks more readable to me, but might also be misleading.

Comment: Ok,I agree that **else & elif** is not required,but they make sure that only one block gets executed for sure,though logically there is no possibility for multiple **if** blocks getting executed in your code cos exception is **raised** .Is there any performance penalty if I use **elif or else** than **if**